# How to send any data from raspberry pi to breadboard wirelessly?

Tags: python, sensor

my question is that how can I send any data from my raspberry pi 3 to breadboard? Since I don't know technical parts very well, I want to do this in simplest way. Assume that  I want to run a python script in my Raspberry and blink a led in breadboard (like this tutorial https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins). Normally, the led is in breadboard and breadboard is connected to Pi with jumper wires. I just want to replace jumper wires with something wireless in a simple way. I don’t want to edit my pyton code (if I have to, I would like to add simple touches).

Actually I gave the LED example to simplfy my question. Because it has just 4 parts and a short python code and I thought if there is a solution to my question, and if someone could help, I could apply it to everything I use raspberry and breadboard. My main situation is that I have a weight sensor and I run a python script and measure the weight (to do this, I got help from this tutorial: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/digital-raspberry-pi-scale-weight-sensor-hx711/) but I edited the script a lot that’s why I don’t want to change it. I just want to remove jumper wires somehow.

So, I hope I explained the situation well. Is that possible? If so, what wireless modules should I use? How many modules should I use? Just 1 to the bread board or 2 modules(1 for bread board, 1 for raspberry)? 
If I use 1 module how can I connect it to the raspberry? If I use 2 modules how can I  pair them? Should I add a power supply to breadboard to send and receive signals? At the end of this, I just want to run my python script in my Raspberry as always with the minimum change of my existing code. If someone helps me with a detailed explanation(connecting mudules and coding parts), tutorials...etc I would be really really glad. Thank you so much.

Comment: share your code that you are using. This is not the right place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1):

1, how to send data from raspberry pi to breadboard wirelessly?

well you can't. The tutorial describe what breadboard is,The breadboard is a way of connecting electronic components to each other without having to solder them together. They are often used to test a circuit design before creating a Printed Circuit Board (PCB).

2, if you want to the **raspberry pi** and **Weight Sensor HX711** to communicate wirelessly

you gone need another raspberry pi,2 wifi or bluetooth module, so you can place the first raspberry pi with the weight sensor to detect change and send data to the second raspberry pi. considering the distance between the two raspberry pis decide using wifi or blutooth and place on both raspberry pi to communicate each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that you would need some active electronics in the breadboard in order to do that. What you want to do reminds me of circuits that are put between a breadboard and your pc/raspberry etc so as not to harm them (e.g. http://www.arunet.co.uk/tkboyd/ele9ppp.htm)if e.g. you shortcut something, only you want a wireless such system.

This is probably not the best forum to ask your question as it has to do imho with hardware. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ might be better, as it will be looked by experts, plus any answer will benefit more people as most people would be looking there.